# Keras tuner, results_summary not showing corresponding trial directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

After having ran an Hyperparameter search with Keras like so:

```
tuner = kt.BayesianOptimization(
  build_model,
  objective=kt.Objective("my_obj_fn", direction="min"),
  max_trials=5,
  directory=files_dir+'my_dir')

X_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = bot.return_data()

tuner.search(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

tuner.results_summary(num_trials=10)
```

the results/checkpoints are in subdirectories in `my_dir` named `trial_****`. The function `results_summary()` displays for each trials theses lines:

```
Trial summary
Hyperparameters:
units: 128
rate: 0.0001
learning_rate: 0.01
Score: 0.0036238597240298986
```

but it DOES NOT specify to which `trial_***` directory it belongs to.

Any cue ?

Regards